# Jumpy transition when only modifying box-shadow, looks fine with box-shadow + border

Tags: css

The following code snippets show two examples of a text input field. When focused, the bottom of the input increases in thickness and changes color.

The first example uses a combination of border-bottom and box-shadow to achieve the effect. The second example uses just box-shadow. I think that the effects should be identical. However, the box-shadow only example 'jumps' when finishing its transition. Why? Is there a way to improve it?

Example has only been tested on the stable version of Webkit.

```css
input[type="text"] {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  padding: 0 0 8px 0;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s, border 0.3s;
  will-change: box-shadow, border;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#example1 {
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}
#example1:focus {
  border-bottom-color: #2196F3;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 #2196F3;
}
#example2 {
  border-bottom: none;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .26);
}
#example2:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 #2196F3;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="example1" placeholder="I'm a good example">
<input type="text" id="example2" placeholder="I'm a bad example">
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine when I run it, and I'm on Chrome.

The first thing you should do is ensure that you have an up to date browser: transition was only universally adopted a few releases ago.

Secondly, transitions don't work perfectly on every element, or work at all on some.

Use this awesome tool to check the elements you are trying to animate for compatibility:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Comment: I'm running on the latest Chrome and I checked the Developer channel, as well. I'm developing a chrome extension, so I only need to target Chrome, as stated in the problem description.

If you turn up the transition-duration to a larger value, maybe that would help you see it? The second example very much so does jump!

Answer (score 0):

```css
    input[type="text"] {
      border-top: none;
      border-left: none;
      border-right: none;
      padding: 0 0 8px 0;
      transition: box-shadow 0.3s, border 0.3s;
      will-change: box-shadow, border;
      outline: none;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    #example1 {
      border-bottom-width: 1px;
      border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    }
    #example1:focus {
      border-bottom-color: #2196F3;
      box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 #2196F3;
    }
    #example2 {
      border-bottom: none;
      padding-bottom: 9px;
      box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .26);
      transition: box-shadow .1s;
    }
    #example2:focus {
      box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 #2196F3;
      transition: box-shadow .4s;
    }
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="example1" placeholder="I'm a good example">
    <input type="text" id="example2" placeholder="I'm a bad example">
```

Comment: I don't believe this changed anything. If you turn up your transition-durations from .1s and .3s to, say, 2s you can see that example2 still jumps at the end of the transition where the first one does not.